# Initializing jquery from Node

Tags: jquery, node.js, init

I  am creating a new project using the following:

```
$mkdir X
$cd X
$npm install jquery
```

Then create a new app.js file:

```
var http = require('http');
var $ = require('jquery');
console.log("http="+ http);
console.log("$="+ $);
console.log("$.getJSON="+ $.getJSON);
```

Output is:

```
http=[object Object]
$=function ( w ) {...}
$.getJSON=undefined
```

Why is $.getJSON undefined ? Using latest io.js v2.4.0.

Comment: I suspect getJSON doesn't work in node. This code works perfectly in the browser.

Comment: Take a look at this (from me) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31405815/2295964) it may clarify `jquery` + `node` combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create an [`XHR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) from within Node.js. This is not going to work since Node.js is simply a JavaScript runtime and is not the same as a browser.

If you want to fetch something from somewhere over HTTP protocol, you can use something like [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). For example (from official docs):

```js
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31405815/2295964) (also from me) for more information on using jQuery in combination with Node.js.

**UPDATE[d again!]:**

So you wanted to know how jQuery node module differentiates between browser and node environment? When you `require` jQuery inside a CommonJS or similar environment which provide `module` and `module.exports`, what you get is a factory and not the actual jQuery object. As you can see below, that factory can be used to create a jQuery object, i.e. using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom):

```js
let jsdom = require("jsdom");
let $ = null;

jsdom.env(
  "http://quaintous.com/2015/07/31/jquery-node-mystery/",
  function (err, window) {
    $ = require('jQuery')(window);
  }
);
```

Here is the how jQuery differentiates between browser and io.js (or Node.js):

```js
(function( global, factory ) {

    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
        // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
        // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
        // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
        // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
        // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
        // See ticket #14549 for more info.
        module.exports = global.document ?
            factory( global, true ) :
            function( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            };
    } else {
        factory( global );
    }

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
  // implementation

  return jQuery;
}));
```

I would use jQuery's npm package is meant for [custom builds](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#custom-build-examples) rather than to be used with `require`!

**UPDATE**:

I had the feeling that this subject happens to keep some devs busy, so I combined the couple of my own answers and wrote [an article](http://quaintous.com/2015/07/31/jqery-node-mystery/) about the whole jQuery/Node combination!

Comment: Thanks for jumping in !

I understand Node.js is a JavaScript engine, and not the same as a browser.

However, there is a first-class Node.js npm package.  I am not trying to just use a random js file which may - or not - be browser-dependant. What would be the point to create a Node.Js package for code that does not work with it ?

This page (from 2012) seems to make it very easy but the directions do not work:

http://www.hacksparrow.com/jquery-with-node-js.html

Comment: jQuery does a great job in DOM parsing and manipulation. What you see in that article is parsing and manipulation. However, all other functionalities which are wrappers for native browser APIs (e.g. `ajax`) are not going to work in node.

Comment: I see - so is jquery under the hood checking the hosting environment and it does not initialize functions (eg. getJSON) which may rely on browsers' capabilities ?

It would explain why jquery.getJSON is undefined from node, but valid in the browser.

Comment: @loictregan Take a look at the file delivered with jQuery's node module. I added the most important part to the answer!

Comment: @loictregan glad I could help :)

Comment: @loictregan I couldn't just let it go without deeper explanation, so I [wrote an article](http://quaintous.com/2015/07/31/jqery-node-mystery/) about it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load jquery synchronously you can use something like the following

```
var jsdom  = require('jsdom');
var jQuery = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom('<p><a>jsdom!</a></p>').defaultView);
```